# Changing the title of an ssh connection without modifying remote machines

Tags: ssh, iterm

Is it possible to set the title of an ssh connection by just changing something on my local machine?

I mean I want `ubuntu@ip-10-50-10-152` in the following picture to be changed to a name I like.

And I don't want to change any settings on the remote machine.

[image]

The IP address is difficult to remember, how can I change it to a more readable name?

I want to map each IP address to a different name.

The remote machines in my case are lots of [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances. Some of them only exist for a few days. And new `ec2`s get created frequently.

I use [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) as my macOS terminal. And I couldn't find any plugin that does the thing I want.

Or is there a better ssh management tool that can display custom text on the title of an ssh connection?

Answer (score 4):

The best way (IMO) is to set the necessary variables in your `bash_profile` of your remote machine.  I understand you don't want to *modify* anything on your remote but it's important to note that what you are doing is setting the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`

When logged in to your remote, issue the command `echo $HOSTNAME` and `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`.  More than likely, you will get the hostname of your machine and the second will come up blank meaning that it's unset.

#### Setting the Title

Edit your `.bash_profile` found in your home directory on the remote. This is *your* file and will not affect the rest of the system.  Add the following line:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${HOSTNAME}\007"'
```

The `\033]0;` (`Esc 0;`) is the escape code to set the title.  The `${HOSTNAME}` is the name of your machine.

Save your profile, log out and log back in and your title bar should now reflect your hostname.

#### Connecting via hostname vs IP

There are two ways to do this:

- Set the hostname in DNS
- modify your local `/etc/hosts` file

I prefer to set this in DNS so that the name will be available to all computers across your network.  Going under the assumption that you have a "consumer grade" router (like Linksys or Netgear), you just have to add the hostname to your DHCP static lease (see your router documentation for specifics)

If you're on a corporate network, the Network Admin can add a record to the DNS server pointing to your host.

If those two options aren't available, you can simply edit your local `/etc/hosts` file (need `root` permissions.  Below is my `/etc/hosts` used as an example:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.10.22   fatjoe
```

I added the hostname `fatjoe` to the end of the `hosts` file.  When I save and exit, if I type `ping fatjoe` it immediately begins to ping the correct IP - the change is immediate.

Comment: I found that editing `/etc/hostname` on the remote machine works for me. The remote machine is Ubuntu 14.04. 

It's strange that editing `/etc/hosts` doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I still wish there's a method that doesn't require any modifications on the remote machine.
Windows ssh client, such as Xshell, is able to do this. I just migrated from windows to mac.

Comment: When you are on the remote machine, what does the command `hostname` give you (before you edit the `/etc/hostname` file)?  As far as it being a Windows/Mac thing, it sounds like Xshell was "bodging" this together.  In all my years of working with BSD/Solaris/Windows/Mac, I always set this info on the remote - so it was the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host yourname
    HostName server.example.com
    Port 22
    User root
```

Then use `ssh yourname` and ‘yourname’ will be shown in the title bar.

Comment: No, this method doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: 'youname' only appears in the title bar during the establishment of the ssh connection.

Comment: After the connection is established, it changes back to ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX

Comment: @Brian Strange, it works for me, I have ~10 entries in ssh config like this and it works for me both in Terminal and iTerm.

Comment: There must be something else that affects the title of the tab.

Answer (score 1):

I followed all the answer of this post and the [official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html), but without success.

Checking up further, I discovered the `~/.bashrc` on the target machine was overwriting `$PS1`, and thus putting back the default name.

If you have the same problem, it might be worth looking for those lines in `~/.bashrc` and edit them as to show the title you want (`$NICKNAME` in my case) to appear on the terminal tab.

````
 case "$TERM" in
 xterm*|rxvt*)
     PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}$NICKNAME: \w\a\]$PS1"
     ;;
 *)
     ;;
 esac```
````