# How to set a fixed title for a terminal in Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I am working a lot with terminals in a Mac with OS 10.13.6 and I want to set a title of a terminal (I have several terminal tabs open).

I know that I can select the tab, go to `Shell` -> `Edit Title` and set the title of the terminal.

However, when I - for example - run a command, login to some other computer etc. - that title is always overwritten.

How can I have a FIXED title for a Terminal Tab FOR ALL TIMES (except I turn off/reboot the laptop)?

**Complete example so that my question is REALLY understood:**

1. I open a terminal in the Mac
2. In the manu of the Terminal I select `Shell` -> `Edit Title` and change the title: [image]
3. The title of the tab is like I want it: [image]
4. In that terminal I start `ipython` (AS AN EXAMPLE!!!).
5. The title has been changed. This NOT what I want! [image]
6. I still want the title to be 'Test Title'.

Comment: What steps do you follow to install which version of ipython?

Comment: Irrelevant. I want a fixed terminal title. 

I cannot tell you how I installed every single application.

Comment: My steps work for me, sorry for asking for more detail so I could try and reproduce that my steps work for ipython in addition to the things I tested. (Normal python, bash, fish, vi). I was curious if you just didn’t follow the steps we did or have some other non default item. No worries if you are happy with the answers or waiting for more eyeballs to help.

Comment: I do not know how I did install any application. But when the title of a tab changes - then its the TAB that changes the title (or maybe the terminal application). THAT application is responsible for changing the title of the tab.

Comment: I can try to explain in my answer better.  All programs can send the message to ask terminal to change the tab or change the window titles. Terminal can ignore those commands. One answer explains how to intercept the sending. I explained how to ignore what is sent and that ignore works for every program I try. 100% success in never changing the tab title like you ask.

Comment: So can I send you a message yo give me the login to your bank account? Surely not!
The terminal just lets the app then communicate with it. So it is the responsibility of the TERMINAL to change the title or not. So maybe what I am asking is just impossible!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the Preferences for terminal app
2. Select the profile in use
3. Select "tab" pane on the right
4. Uncheck everything except **Show activity indicator**

[image: terminal settings to prevent bash and shell escape sequences from showing in terminal tabs and title area]

Repeat the above for **Window** title if you want that to change in addition to the tab title. Now, you will only get the defaults when you make new tabs/windows and your manual changes will persist and not reflect the variables that endeavor to provide status each time the command line prompt is regenerated.

[image: Window preferences in terminal.app on macOS Mojave dark mode]

Comment: As an aside, it's hard to resist pointing out the "Escape sequence..." explanation. It's one of the clearest primers I've seen on the whole PS1 / PROMPT_COMMAND / OSC escape sequence rabbit trail that you have to go down to customize these updates. Your case is simple, just turn them off as opposed to crafting or overriding them...

Comment: Thanks for that extensive explanation, but it does not seem to work. I have changed the `tab`preferences as suggested, then I change the title in the Inspector, but as soon as I run e.g. `ipython` the title changes. It seems like the tab title is removed the the terminal title replaced by the `IPython` title. I have made the changes exactly as suggested...

Comment: Are you certain @alex that you unchecked / disabled all 9 window items and all 6 tab items, leaving only “show activity” on as that is irrelevant to the processing of the change messages that ipython and just about every other command will send? I can start and stop the updating at will using only the two preference windows above on all my Macs. I suppose if your terminal preference store is corrupt, you could click and the app is broken... try making a new user account and retest?

Comment: Yes I just checked again with the current user. I can try with a new user account, but it will take a while. I do not know how to make a new user on a mac...

Comment: I just tested with a new user account, but the system behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for checking my suggestion @Alex - I'm afraid I'm out of ideas at this point. I have to assume you're doing what I'm doing and we're just not on to the item that's causing this.

Comment: I've gone through all the steps above and it didn't have any change on the behavior. I've restarted terminal after making the changes and re-set the title and then as soon as I ssh, it resets my title.  Same behavior both with a window and with a tab.  I'm on 10.14.4.  I even created a new profile with a bright green background to make sure I was using the right profile.

Comment: Oh, I think the place I'm SSHing to has the escape characters in its .bashrc file.   `    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ ' seems to be resetting the title even if you don't have the checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the Terminal title is set in the `PROMPT_COMMAND`variable that set in `.bash_profile`

For the location’ see [Changing the Title of an SSH connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/284687/119271).

Just remove the `${HOSTNAME}` variable from the prompt on the remote machine’s `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I am not talking about the title of a ssh connection. I am talking about the title of a terminal tab.

Comment: The answer is exactly the same.  The title of your shell window is changing because something in the shell running inside is changing it.  Remove what's changing it.

Comment: It's typically [Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) being set that causes your tab/window title to change.   The most likely place is your prompt.  Where ever you set your prompt (most likely `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`) is the cause.

Comment: None of the suggestions will work when I run e.g. `ipython`, as there is no ssh connection involved. The title of the tab changes!!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to preferences / profile / window and there is a text box for you to name the terminal window. There are also checkboxes underneath the text box to add other information to the name.  There are similar options in iTerm2.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I deactivated some options, but when I e.g. start `ipython` the title of the tab is changed again.

Comment: Yes i see. I don't understand unless there is a command in iPython to change the terminal name.

Comment: I am pretty sure its not because of python, but because MacOS is a stupid operating system...

Comment: @Alex  Well Unix has been around for many years so enough people like to keep it around for 50 years.  Is sure beats the hell out of Windoze and Linux is just Unix for PCs. So what OS are you using that makes Apple so bad?

Comment: Apple Operating system.

Comment: @Alex  The Apple Operating system is Unix!  If you don't believe it open the Terminal App and type away!

Comment: Yes I know. But what I want does not work. To set a title of a terminal tab which stays the same, no matter what process is started in that tab...